# Lagrange Multipliers Sign and Formulation

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have been trying to understand how Lagrange multipliers and the Lagrangian work.
The Lagrangian is defined as
$$\mathcal{L} = F\left(\mathbf{x}\right) + \mathbf{\lambda}^T\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$$

and can also be defined as
$$\mathcal{L} = F\left(\mathbf{x}\right) - \mathbf{\lambda}^T\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$$

Why add that when $\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{x}\right) = \mathbf{0}$ for the equality constraints? Also, I stumbled on some source saying that the sign in front of $\lambda$ matters when it comes down to more complex optimization (i.e. the Lagrangian is defined as a sum of those 2 terms or a diference of those 2 terms). Can one explain how it is so for both questions?

Comment: The sign usually doesn’t matter. The key thing is that you’re looking for points at which the two gradients are parallel.

Comment: I mean, the sign may matter because according to the KKT conditions, the sign really affects the constraint conditions

Comment: It only matters if you care about the value of $\mathbb\lambda$, which for many applications of this method, you don’t.

Answer (score 1):

**Quote: "Why add that when g(x)=0 for the equality constraints? "**

The full expression for Lagrangian is $$\mathfrak{L}=\mathbf{F}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )-\lambda ^{T}\left ( \mathbf{G\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )-k} \right )$$
where $\mathbf{G\left ( x \right )}=k$ is the equality constraint. Hence, $\mathbf{g\left ( x \right )}=\mathbf{G\left ( x \right )-k}=0$

Regarding the sign in front of the Lagrange Multiplier, if you do $\mathbf{G\left ( x \right )-k}$, the sign is $-$. If you do $\mathbf{k-G\left ( x \right )}$, the sign is $+$. This is to ensure that $\frac{\partial \mathfrak{L}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}-\lambda \frac{\partial \mathbf{G}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$.

If the constraint is an inequality, i.e., $\mathbf{G\left ( x \right )}< \mathbf{k}$, it is preferable that the smaller quantity $\mathbf{G\left ( x \right )}$ is subtracted from the larger quantity $\mathbf{k}$ and form the Lagrangian as $\mathfrak{L}=\mathbf{F\left ( x \right )}+\lambda ^{T}\left ( \mathbf{k}-\mathbf{G\left ( x \right )} \right )$